# How to use ajax in contact form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple contact form that has some validation on it. I have searched Google for hours and found loads of stuff on how to create a contact from that does all kinds of things but I am just looking for something really simple. I want to use my form as is expect for the fact that I want to add some ajax code to make the page not reload as it is now, and show a little animated gif replacing the submit button while the form is submitting and then show the success message that I have.

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$error = ""; $successMessage = "";
$fname = $email = $message = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $error .= "First name is required.<br>";
  } else {
    $fname = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$fname)) {
      $error .= "Only letters and white space allowed.<br>"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $error .= "Email is required.<br>";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $error .= "Invalid email format.<br>"; 
    }
  }


  if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
      $error .= "Message is required.<br>";
  } else {
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
  }

    if ($error != "") {

            $error = '<div class="formerror" role="alert"><p><strong>There were error(s) in your form:</strong><br></p>' . $error . '</div>';
 } else {

     $successMessage = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Your message was sent, we\'ll get back to you ASAP!</div>';

           // $emailTo = "me@mydomain.com";

            //$subject = $_POST['subject'];

            //$content = $_POST['content'];

        //    $headers = "From: ".$_POST['email'];

        //    if (mail($emailTo, $subject, $content, $headers)) {

          //      $successMessage = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Your message was sent, we\'ll get back to you ASAP!</div>';


        //    } else {

        //        $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p><strong>Your message couldn\'t be sent - please try again later</div>';

            }
 //}

}



function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}


?>
```

Form code:

```
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
  <div class="cform">
    <input type="text" class="contactfield cformbottom" id="name" placeholder="Your full name" name="name" value="<?php echo $fname;?>">

    <input type="email" class="contactfield cformbottom" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">


    <textarea class="contactfield" id="message" name="message" rows="3" placeholder="Your Message" value="<?php echo $message;?>"></textarea>
          </div>
  <input type="submit" class="newsbut" value="Submit">
</form><br>
         <div id="error"><? echo $error.$successMessage; ?></div>
```

jQuery validation:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

          $("form").submit(function(e) {

              var error = "";

              if ($("#name").val() == "") {

                  error += "Your name is required.<br>"

              }

              if ($("#email").val() == "") {

                  error += "Your email is required.<br>"

              }

              if ($("#message").val() == "") {

                  error += "Your message is required.<br>"

              }

              if (error != "") {

                 $("#error").html('<div class="formerror" role="alert"><p><strong>There were error(s) in your form:</strong></p>' + error + '</div>');

                  return false;

              } else {

                  return true;

              }
          })


    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method I have posted below. Just read the comments above the function and call the function with appropriate parameters.
Before calling remote_call you can call another method, load_image, and after the response in callback, call your deload_image function.

This is older way of sending ajax requests. The apis will be removed soon, just that createbrowser object function (last method below will be required to be modified).

Also please notice that in below methods a custom Alert function is called which is to modify the behavior of alert functions
    //============================================================================================//
    //========================================= SEND AJAX REQUEST ================================//
    //============================================================================================//
    /*
    mandatory   object. It should have various properties as described below. Some are madatory and other optional
    mandatory   object.actionScriptURL  =   relative path(relative to doc root of server) of page , which is to be called
                            It can also be urlwith query string along
    optional    object.sendMethod       =   POST/GET. Default value is post
    optional    object.callType         =   ASYNC/SYNC. Default value is ASYNC
    optional    object.additionalData   =   AnyData to be sent like formdata or else
    optional    object.callBack         =   Any function to be called back wid response from server. If function as an object is being passed then that function must have an argument provisioning
    */

```
function send_remoteCall(object)
{
    var callType = true, sendMethod =   'POST', additionalData  =   null, callBack  =   '';
    if(IsValueNull(object.actionScriptURL))
        return false;

    if(IsValueNull(object.sendMethod))
        sendMethod  =   'POST';

    if(!IsValueNull(object.callType) && object.callType ==  'SYNC') 
        callType    =   false;

    additionalData  =   object.additionalData;

    var xmlHttp =   createBrowserObject();
    if(!IsValueNull(object.callBack) )
    {
        callBack    =   object.callBack; 
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange  =   function(){
            if(xmlHttp.readyState   ==  4 && xmlHttp.status ==  200)
            callBack(xmlHttp.responseText);
        }; 
    }
    xmlHttp.open(sendMethod,object.actionScriptURL,callType);
    if(additionalData != null && additionalData != undefined ){
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", additionalData.length);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    }
    xmlHttp.send(additionalData); 
}

function loadImage()
{
    //document.getElementById('LayOutDiv').style.display = "block";
    //showCenter('<div id="fade"><img src="../../Common/images/aloader.gif"></div>');
    //document.getElementById('LayOutDiv').innerHTML = '<img src="../../Common/images/aloader.gif">'; 
    var LoadingImage    =   document.getElementById('LoadingImage');
    if(!IsValueNull(LoadingImage)){
        LoadingImage.style.display = "block";
        showCenter('LoadingImage');
    }
    LayOutDiv   =   document.getElementById('LayOutDiv');
    if(!IsValueNull(LayOutDiv))
        LayOutDiv.style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(deloadImage, 15000);
}

/*=======================================================*/
//===========FUNCTION TO HIDE THE LOADING EFFECT==========
/*======================================================*/

function deloadImage()
{
    //document.getElementById('LayOutDiv').innerHTML = ''; 
    LoadingImage= document.getElementById('LoadingImage');
    if(!IsValueNull(LoadingImage))
        LoadingImage.style.display = "none";
    LayOutDiv   =   document.getElementById('LayOutDiv');
    if(!IsValueNull(LayOutDiv))
        LayOutDiv.style.display = "none";
}


//==============================================================================================//
//========================= CREATE BROWSE OBJECT FOR AJAX =======================//
//==============================================================================================//
function createBrowserObject()
{
    if(xmlHttp)
        delete xmlHttp;

    var xmlHttp;
    try
    {
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();   // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari      
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        try
        {
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer                   
        } 
        catch (e)
        { 
            try
            {
                xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e)
            { 
                Alert(JavascriptNotWorking); 
            }
        }
    }

    return xmlHttp;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Where would I put this code in relation to my code?

Comment: You can remove the form tag.

Change your submit button by changing it to type="button"
Also create your function in javascript to be called on click of this button create dbove.
From your function collect the data into an object as documented in send_remote_call function. pass the parameters to this function and you are done. You can recieve the response back in your own callback and also manage load or deload image with function described above